# Add a new activity (class + xml) premade in project

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

When a new project is created, a screen is shown to select pre made screens with login screen, maps screen,  blank, empty, etc.

Can i add a new screen to my current project selecting one of this pre made screens? or this screen is only shown in project creating?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, right-click you project folder and then `New` > `Activity` > `Gallery...`

Here's the screenshot for it:

[image]